# Class '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docID'. Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' Tried calling: docID

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("pet_entries")
    .doc(data[index].docID)
    .delete()
```

i m not catch the data[index].docID

In this, I faced an issue in (data[index].docID). i solve this issue after researching that firebase deprecates docID to id then I just replace it with

.doc(data[index].id)